# getData does not reflect changes made on the Tabulator table

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am new to JavaScript and Tabulator, I am stuck at this place, your help is appreciated.

I have loaded the data on the tabulator table and making few changes to it (add new column, deleting column etc.), these changes are reflected on the table but when I use table.getData() updated data is not reflected (old data is reflected). I need this to use some other places. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the sample code.

```
tabulatorTable = new Tabulator("#dfTable", {
selectable:true,
data:dataJson,
layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
responsiveLayout:"hide",  //hide columns that dont fit on the table
tooltips:true,            //show tool tips on cells
addRowPos:"top",          //when adding a new row, add it to the top of 
//table
history:true,             //allow undo and redo actions on the table
pagination:"local",       //paginate the data
paginationSize:20,         
movableColumns:true,      //allow column order to be changed
resizableRows:true,       //allow row order to be changed

columns:[
        {title:"YearsExperience", field:"YearsExperience", editor:"number"},
        {title:"Salary", field:"Salary", sorter:"number"}
        ]

});

tabulatorTable.addColumn({formatter:"rownum", title:"id"}); **// Adding new column to the table**
console.log(tabulatorTable.getData()); **// Does not reflect the newly added column**
```

Expected Json file to contain added column data (title - "id")

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify data just by adding a column to the grid.  Additionally, the column you added is a "rownum" formatter and is not bound to a field, so what key would it know to add?  You will need to explicitly modify the data on the table.

See here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/update

Answer (score 0):

Solved it  see snippet

```
tabulatorTable.addColumn({
  formatter: "rownum",
  field: "id",
  title: "id"
});
```

```js
const dataJson = [{
    'YearsExperience': 2,
    'Salary': 40000
  },
  {
    'YearsExperience': 3,
    'Salary': 50000
  },
]


const tabulatorTable = new Tabulator("#dfTable", {
  selectable: true,
  data: dataJson,
  layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table
  responsiveLayout: "hide", //hide columns that dont fit on the table
  tooltips: true, //show tool tips on cells
  addRowPos: "top", //when adding a new row, add it to the top of 
  //table
  history: true, //allow undo and redo actions on the table
  pagination: "local", //paginate the data
  paginationSize: 20,
  movableColumns: true, //allow column order to be changed
  resizableRows: true, //allow row order to be changed
  columns: [{
      title: "YearsExperience",
      field: "YearsExperience",
      editor: "number"
    },
    {
      title: "Salary",
      field: "Salary",
      sorter: "number"
    }
  ]

});

tabulatorTable.addColumn({
  formatter: "rownum",
  field: "id",
  title: "id"
}); // Adding new column to the table**
console.log(tabulatorTable.getData()); // Does not reflect the newly added column**
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.2.7/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.2.7/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="dfTable"></div>
```